# How does the order of expressions in an if block with && matter?

Tags: c#

I have an if block being called in an update function of a game in C# unity 3D. Needless to say, it will be called a lot, so I'm trying to optimize as much as I can. I have two checks I need to make:

```
if (playerIsFlagged == true){
    if (player.distance < 10){
        doaction()
    }
}
```

Now, for every update being called, I want to check the simple playerIsFlagged first, and then the distance. So I wrote:

```
if (playerIsFlagged == true && player.distance < 10){
     doaction()
}
```

In this case, will the code always test both variable values before failing the if test, or when it checks that the first (playerisFlagged) is false it will automatically skip the second (distance) check?

In other words, is there a difference in performance in both cases?

Comment: They are identical.  Side note:  you dont have to put `== true`, you can just say `if(playerIsFlagged)`

Comment: quick question.. should duplicates be downvoted? I understand the dupe flag, not the downvote.

Comment: @raphadko The fact that a question is a duplicate does not necessarily mean that it should be downvoted.  But dupes are more likely to get downvotes because somebody feels you should have done more research before posting.

Comment: @raphadko [discussion on downvoting duplicates on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334361/downvote-duplicate-question), which is itself, ironically, a duplicate.

Comment: It's unlikely that having a single line `if` will have different performance than your multi if version.  I wouldn't be surprised if the IL was identical for each version in a release build.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, if playerIsFlagged is true, then it will check the second condition.

In the second case, if playerIsFlagged is false it will skip the second case. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `if(booleanValue == true)` is redundant, you can just write `if(booleanValue)` or `if(!booleanValue)` to check for false.

In response to your question, using double `&&` means just that, check the first operando and if false ignore the rest. The same rule applies for double `||`